# mcrypt_get_block_size undefined in AWS server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on integrating payments with Paytm into my site using the Codeigniter framework, so I have placed `config_paytm.php` and `encdec_paytm.php` in a third_party folder. After checkout, I am getting the error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_block_size()

Filename: paytmlib/encdec_paytm.php

Line Number: 5
```

Comment: mcrypt is old, insecure and in the process of being phased out.  Your best option is to modernise your code to not depend on mcrypt. https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong

Comment: So which code should i use

Comment: Literally anything else.  See linked articles for some suggestions, also PHP 7.x introduces new encryption helpers that are a lot easier to use and more modern

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @GordonM Can you provide a link to the new PHP encryption helpers mentioned in your comment?